# Pip doesn't install packages to activated virtualenv, ignores requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am attempting to setup a development environment on my new dev machine at home. I have just installed Ubuntu and now I am attempting to clone a remote repo from our web-server and install its dependencies so I can begin work.

So far I have manually installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` from pypi and edited my bash.rc appropriately to source my virtualenvs when i start my terminal. I then cloned my repo to `~/projects/project-name/websitename.com`. Then I used `virtualenvwrapper` to `mkvirtualenv env-name` from `~/projects/project-name/websitename.com`. This reflects exactly the `file-structure/setup` of the web-server I am cloning from. So far so good.

I logged into the dev server and activate the `virtualenv` there and use `pip freeze -l > req.txt` to render a dependencies list and scp to my local machine. I activate the `virtualenv` on my local machine, navigate to the `~/projects/project-name/websitename.com` and execute `pip install -r path-to-req.txt` and it runs through all of the dependencies as if nothing is wrong. However, when i attempt to `manage.py syncdb` i get an error about not finding core django packages. What the hell? So i figure somehow Django failed to install, i `run pip install Django==1.5.1` and it completes successfully. I got to setup my site again and get another error about no module named `django_extensions`. Okay, what the hell with it, i just installed all of these packages with pip?!

So i `pip freeze -l > test.txt` and `cat test.txt`, what does it list? `Django==1.5.1`, the one package I just manually installed. Why isn't pip installing my dependencies from my specified list into my virtualenv? What am I messing up here?

-EDIT-------------

Which pip gives me the path to pip in my virtualenv

I have only 1 virtualenv and it is activated

Comment: Everything you are doing seems ok, try to debug with `which pip`.

Comment: also try `find ~/.virtualenvs -type d -iname "anypackage"` to see if your required packages are installed or not. Also I recommend using `https://gist.github.com/insin/1425703` which will give nice prompt about activated virtualenv in your bash.

Comment: running your command, the only packages in my virtualenv is the one I manually asked pip to install Django, all others processed by pip in the requirements file were ignored. I also somehow get a nice prompt indicating which virtualenv I have activated.

Comment: I can only recommend going through `pip install -r` again and see if any  error is occuring in some specific package. You seem to do everything okay.

Comment: @sagarchalis Okay, i will try this shortly. As you said, something must be failing somewhere..

Comment: I recently encountered this problem on my Fedora Core 19 box.`pip install -r requirements.txt`  wouldnt work for me. However, when I went through the list manually e.g. `pip install Cython` it worked fine.

Comment: I encountered this symptom for Python 3 and found this page: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/532 - it was solved by upgrading the installed version of virtualenv from 1.11 to 1.11.2

Comment: what is happening when you download the package manually and install using setup.py

Answer (score 6):

My usual workflow is to

```
pip freeze > someFile.txt
```

and then install with

```
pip install -r someFile.txt
```

So I'm certain that this should work just fine. Unfortunately I can't really tell you anything besides make sure to check that

1. You really are in the virtualenv that you think you are in. Make sure to run

   ```
   workon yourVirtualEnvName
   ```

   to activate it just in case that matters.
2. Make sure to check that pip is within your virtualenv.

   ```
   which pip
   ```

   gives me

   ```
   /path/to/home/.virtualenvs/myVirtEnv/bin/pip
   ```

Sorry I can't give you a more concrete answer. I have to do this semi-regularly and I've never had a problem with it skipping dependencies. Best of luck!

Comment: Huh, yeah, im running pip install -r someFile.txt and I even watch as it says it's downloading and installing but then the packages don't exist. For example it says:

Downloading/unpacking django-extensions==1.1.1 (from -r req.txt (line 14))
  Downloading django-extensions-1.1.1.tar.gz (149kB): 149kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-extensions

. But django-extensions doens't appear to be installed and still causes an error when called. It also doesn't appear when I pip freeze..

Comment: did you file a solution to this? I am having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Struggled with some variation of this issue not long ago; it ended up being my cluttered `.bash_profile` file.

Make sure you don't have anything that might mess up your virtualenv inside your `.bash_profile`/`.bashrc`, such as `$VIRTUAL_ENV` or `$PYTHONHOME` or `$PYTHONPATH` environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just encountered a similar problem. In my case the cause was that I was running the `pip install` command using `sudo`. This made the command run globally and the packages install in the global python path.

Hope that helps somebody.